# Get row for each user where the count of a value in a column is maximum

Tags: sql, sql-server

My column structure:

```
Column0   Column1
aaa        abc
aaa        abc
aaa        xyx
aaa        NA
bbb        fgh
bbb        NA
bbb        NA
bbb        NA
ccc        NA
ccc        NA
ccc        NA
ccc        NA
```

What I wish to get is foreach distinct 'Column0' data 'Column1' data whose count is max unless that data is NA in which case get the second highest.
If for a 'Column0' data all values of 'Column1' are NA then the value can be NA

So expected value:

```
Column0   Column1
aaa       abc
bbb       fgh
ccc       NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give the correct result:

```
DECLARE @t table(Column0  char(3), Column1 varchar(3))
INSERT @t values
('aaa','abc'),('aaa','abc'),('aaa','xyx'),('aaa','NA')
,('bbb','fgh'),('bbb','NA'),('bbb','NA'),('bbb','NA')
,('ccc','NA'),('ccc','NA'),('ccc','NA'),('ccc','NA')

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT
    column0, 
    column1, 
    count(case when column1 <> 'NA' THEN 1 end) over (partition by column0, column1) cnt
  FROM @t
), CTE2 as
(
  SELECT 
    column0, 
    column1, 
    row_number() over (partition by column0 order by cnt desc) rn
  FROM CTE
)
SELECT column0, column1
FROM CTE2
WHERE rn = 1
```

Result:

```
column0  column1
aaa      abc
bbb      fgh
ccc      NA
```

Comment: plz have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072777/get-row-for-each-user-where-the-count-of-a-value-in-a-column-is-maximum

Answer (score 2):

You can use two CTEs and the ranking function `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT Column0, Column1, Cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Column0, Column1)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
, CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT Column0, Column1,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column0  
                                   ORDER BY CASE WHEN Column1 = 'NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC
                                          , Cnt DESC)
    FROM CTE1
)
SELECT Column0, Column1
FROM CTE2
WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8093e/4/0)</kbd>

Comment: you didn't get the rows with the highest count, you got the rows with the lowest ascii value in column1

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: now i've got it, i've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: if i add ('aaa','xyx'),('aaa','xyx') to the test data, I would expect to get aaa, xyx as result. This doesn't happen. It still returns aaa, abc. Your partition only covers column0, it should include both columns

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: i don't understand, here is your sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8093e/1/0 What do you expect instead?

Comment: this would give the correct result if you added column1 to your first partition like i described in my last comment

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: i'm slow on the uptake today, you're right. `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Column0, Column1)` is correct

Comment: plz have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072777/get-row-for-each-user-where-the-count-of-a-value-in-a-column-is-maximum

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
select T1.Column0,
       isnull((
              select top(1) T2.Column1
              from dbo.YourTable as T2
              where T1.Column0 = T2.Column0 and
                    T2.Column1 <> 'NA'
              group by T2.Column1
              order by count(*) desc
              ), 'NA') as Column1
from dbo.YourTable as T1
group by T1.Column0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/875fb/2)

And with an index

```
create index IX_YourTable_Column0 on YourTable(Column0, Column1)
```

You get a nice looking query plan.

[image]

And a version that deals with NULL values in `Column0`.

```
select T1.Column0,
       isnull((
              select top(1) T2.Column1
              from dbo.YourTable as T2
              where exists(select T1.Column0 intersect select T2.Column0) and
                    T2.Column1 <> 'NA'
              group by T2.Column1
              order by count(*) desc
              ), 'NA') as Column1
from dbo.YourTable as T1
group by T1.Column0
```

The query plan for for this version is the same as the one above.

Comment: This one is really nice

Comment: I see a problem, you are joining on column0. If there are 100 rows with the same column0, you will get 10.000 count in the subselect. There is also a risk if column1 contains NULL as a valid value, those will not be counted

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I do a group by in the outer query so the lower branch of the plan (the nested query) will only execute one time for each distinct value of Column0.

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifiing, I missed that. The null values can still be an issue though

Comment: Plz have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072777/get-row-for-each-user-where-the-count-of-a-value-in-a-column-is-maximum

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Added a version that deals with nulls in Column0.

Comment: i was thinking about null in second column. Had not considered that the first column could also be null. Second column null is still messing with your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` with an aggregation:

```
select column0, column1
from (select column0, column1,
             row_number() over (partition by column0
                                order by count(*) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from [table]
      group by column0, column1
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want to allow duplicates in the case of ties, then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: this will return 6 rows, it should only return 3

Comment: @Amab . . . That shouldn't not have had `column1` in the `partition by` clause.  I do think this is the simplest way of getting what you want.