# Get row for each user where the count of a value in a column is maximum ++

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question is an update to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071104/get-row-for-each-user-where-the-count-of-a-value-in-a-column-is-maximum/).

My column structure:

```
Column0   Column1   Column2
aaa        abc      a
aaa        abc      a
aaa        abc      b
aaa        abc      a
aaa        abc      b
aaa        abc      NA
aaa        xyx      b
aaa        NA       b
bbb        fgh      v
bbb        fgh      NA
bbb        fgh      NA
bbb        NA       m
bbb        NA       m
bbb        NA       m
bbb        NA       NA
bbb        NA       NA
ccc        NA       NA
ccc        NA       NA
ccc        NA       NA
```

What I wished to get earlier was foreach distinct 'Column0' data 'Column1' data whose count is max unless that data is NA in which case get the second highest.
If for a 'Column0' data all values of 'Column1' are NA then the value can be NA.

The same rule applies here as well. Moreover for 'Column2', I wish to apply the same rule over the expected answer of 'Column1'

So even though for 'Column0' value 'aaa' the number of 'Column2' values for b is more, I wish to get the answer for 'Column2' as a.
This is because the query result in 'Column1' is 'abc' for 'Column0' value 'aaa' and amongst the said 'Column1' values in 'Column2', 'a' is more.

Similarly, even though for 'Column0' value 'bbb' the number of 'Column2' values for m and NA is more, I wish to get the answer for 'Column2' as v.

As earlier we do not take the value NA into account unless all values are NA.

So expected value:

```
Column0   Column1   Column2
aaa       abc       a
bbb       fgh       v
ccc       NA        NA
```

All help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: please don't comment on previous questions/answers and ask people to look at your new question. the active users will naturally look at questions when they are online, they don't need to be pinged with messages. users give up their own time to help, they don't expect someone to contact them directly calling for help.

Answer (score 0):

Same as used in the responses of the previous question, you can use the `count` window function, but add an extra `count` partitioned over all columns, and ordering the `row_number` first over the prevalent values in column1, and then over the prevalent values of both columns.

```
;WITH Counts AS
(
    SELECT column0, column1, column2,
           COUNT(nullif(column1,'NA')) OVER (PARTITION BY column0, column1) cntCol1,
           COUNT(nullif(Column2,'NA')) OVER (PARTITION BY Column0, Column1,  Column2) cntCol2
    FROM @t
)
, ranked AS
(
    SELECT column0, column1, column2,
           row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Column0  ORDER BY cntcol1 desc, cntcol2 desc) rnr
    FROM counts
)
SELECT Column0, Column1, Column2
FROM ranked
where rnr = 1
```

The column2 records will be inside the prevalent column1 records because the first order by on cntcol1 forces those records to come first and because cntCol2 is based on both column2 and column1, its value will be based on the count of column2 inside column1 (and column0 which is the primary partition).

`NullIf(column,'NA')` is used to force 'NA' to get a lower value on both `count`s.